# Copying a File From Share Drive To Remote Desktop Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, remote-access, filepath, network-drive

Im currently running the task of putting a start up script that i have on every computer on the network using powershell and this is what i have so far

```
robocopy "S:\03 - Section Folders\04 - SCM\scripts\startupscript.vbs" 
"$cheese\c$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" /r:1 /w:0
```

so far when i run it i get an error

```
2020/06/23 14:40:56 ERROR 267 (0x0000010B) Accessing Source Directory S:\03 - Section Folders\04 - 
SCM\scripts\startupscript.vbs\
The directory name is invalid.
```

the intended outcome for this script is to pull the file i need form a network drive and save it to all of the computers on the network. as far as i can tell my only problem is that the file path from the network drive isn't being recognized.

Comment: Thanks @Sid for the input, it definitely went somewhere but still kicked back this error 
    2020/06/23 14:55:26 ERROR 53 (0x00000035) Accessing Source Directory \\03 - Section Folders\04 - SCM\scripts\startupscript.vbs\
The network path was not found.

Comment: From the looks of the error message it thinks that startupscript.vbs is a directrory (the trailing \ is the clue) not a file? Is it?

Comment: @RetiredGeek it is a file, i can get it to run using the script from a local file path but for some reason using the file from my network drive it wont run, essentially i want it to copy to a start up folder so it runs on startup

Answer (score 0):

Zizzay,

Since you're only copying a single file I would recommend not using RoboCopy but rather Copy-Item.

```
$CIArgs = @{
    Path        = $("S:\03 - Section Folders\04 - " +
                     "SCM\scripts\startupscript.vbs")
    Destination = $("$cheese\c$\ProgramData\Microsoft\" +
                    "Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
    Force       = $True
}

Copy-Item @CIArgs
```

HTH